# Tracking parent list in nested list

Tags: r, loops, nested

I have a nested loop that I need to iterate over. I want to go to the end of the list (in this case second item of the parent list), and add item to it if it isn't nested loop anymore. So loop may have many levels of nested loop. Right now, I'm only getting second list as a return. How do I track parent list?

```
a <- list( x = list(1,2,3),y =list(4,5,6))
 con=TRUE
 while(con){
 i <-length(a)
 for(k in i:i){
 if(!typeof(a[[k]])=="list"){
   a[[k+1]] <- "test"
   con=FALSE
  }else{
  a <- a[[k]]
   i <- length(a)
 }
 }
}


Expected Result:a <- list(x = list(1,2,3), y =list(4,5,6, "test"))
Result: a <- list(4,5,6,"test")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(magrittr)
a <- list( x = list(1,2,3),y =list(4,5,6), z = 1)

temp <- lapply(a, typeof) %>% unlist
tempList <- (temp!="list")

if (sum(tempList) > 0) {
  a[[max(which(tempList == FALSE))]] %<>% append("test")
} else {
  a[[length(a)]] %<>% append("test")
}
```

It isn't clear to me what it is that you want to do, but 
just concentrating on your example, this would work.

In short, see which elements of the parent list are not Lists, and for the last one of them add "test". If all of them are lists, then add "test" to the last one.